# Как в строке подсчитать сумму не целых чисел

Tags: javascript

Javascript

```
 var stroka = "48,500 52 68,320";
```

В результате получить **168,820**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var stroka = "48,500 52 68,320";
var summ = 0.0; 
stroka.split(' ').map(item => {
   summ += parseFloat(item.replace(',', '.'));
   return item;
})
// устанавливаем float с 3мя знаками после запятой
result = summ.toFixed(3) + "";
result = result.replace('.', ',')
```

Использован новый стандарт функций называемый "arrow functions" из ES6, введен уже в Chrome, Firefox. Не поддерживается пока Opera и Safari

Пример через стандартную функцию:

```
var stroka = "48,500 52 68,320";
var summ = 0.0; 
stroka.split(' ').map(function(item) {
   summ += parseFloat(item.replace(',', '.'));
   return item;
})
// устанавливаем float с 3мя знаками после запятой
result = summ.toFixed(3) + "";
result = result.replace('.', ',')
```

Comment: спасибо, а вот чтобы результат был формата не 168,82, а 168,820 это возможно?

Comment: `(item) =>` на `function (item)` поменяйте

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик почитай документацию если интересно, как написан код, это ES6, я изменил пост с описанием этого

Comment: Василий Барбашев, я просто сторонник максимальной адаптации под браузеры. У меня 3 браузера Ваш код не схавали. Про стандарт вкурсе.

Comment: @sashatexb У меня вопрос, если это целые числа, лишь разделенные запятой (каждая тройка чисел), то алгоритм надо сделать другой, т.к иначе получается что мы складываем не целые числа такие как 48.5 + 52 + 68.32. Если складывать целые числа то у нас получится 168820, и только тогда можно разбить строку и разделить числа запятой, если надо, могу сделать

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик поэтому я и подкорректировал код) Спасибо за исправление

Comment: @Василий Барбашев чисел будет много, т.к. подгружать я их буду из json файла, вряд ли подойдет ваш пример или я не прав?

Comment: @sashatexb чисел может быть сколько угодно, просто js сам обрезает нули у чисел типа Float, так это у вас целые числа или с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @sashatexb я поправил пример, добавил .toFixed(3) к выводу суммы

Comment: @Василий Барбашев с плавающей точкой

Comment: @sashatexb проверяй, я пример отредактировал

Comment: @Василий Барбашев спасибо, все супер работает!!!